# How to log navigation back stack in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

An example, the app first starts with screen A in the back stack, then navigates to screen B, then navigates again to screen C, and finally popUpTo Inclusive back to class A.

```
|--------|     |--------|     |--------|      |--------|
|    A   |  => |    B   | =>  |    C   |  =>  |    A   |
|--------|     |--------|     |--------|      |--------|
               |    A   |     |    B   |
               |--------|     |--------|
                              |    A   |
                              |--------|
```

How can I log what is inside the back stack for every change after a certain action like pop and navigate was done, that happens in my application?

Comment: What do you mean by "every changes", can you clarify?

Comment: What I mean by every change is when I do actions like pop, navigate, etc. Then I could see the current backstack after the action was done.

Answer (score 4):

Use `currentBackStack.value` instead `backQueue`

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, _, _ ->
    val routes = controller
        .currentBackStack.value
        .map { it.destination.route }
        .joinToString(", ")

    Log.d("BackStackLog", "BackStack: $routes")
}
```

Comment: `currentBackStack` is highlighted with an error in the IDE: "NavController.currentBackStack can only be accessed from within the same library group". However, it seems to compile and run fine -- I probably wouldn't use it in production but for testing it's okay. Another caveat is that by the time the listener gets called the backstack doesn't seem to have been updated.

Answer (score 0):

use OnDestinationChangedListener to monitor back stack.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { controller, destination, arguments ->
    logBackStack(controller)
}

private fun logBackStack(controller: NavController) {
    val backStack = StringBuilder("Back Stack: ")
    
    controller.backStack.forEach { entry ->
        backStack.append(entry.destination.label).append(" -> ")
    }
    
    Log.d("BackStackLog", backStack.toString())
}
```

Comment: Unresolved reference: backStack